# Get a CSS style value from custom component

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6

I have a style:

```
.rating{
      fontSize:24;
}
```

and a custom MXML Component of type s|Graphic. How can I get the fontSize value from the component in actionscript?

I tried:

```
public var fff:String = getStyle("fontSize"); //undefined (runtime error)
public var fff2:String = this.getStyle("fontSize"); // undefined (compile time error)
```

Comment: What do you mean by off?? I am pretty sure its fontSize in flex, there's even no code hinting for font-size.

Comment: have a look at this http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_08.html

Comment: That was helpful, solved it by adding this line in initialize function: somevar = this.getStyle("fontSize"); Add it as an answer please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this page for more info.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_08.html

`somevar = this.getStyle("fontSize");` add to initialize function